# My Keras predict_generator gives complete black output

Tags: deep-learning, keras, tensorflow, image

I am working on a image-to-image translation problem and trying to work with a basic UNet. But strangely I am getting complete black image prediction everytime with keras.predict_generator, even if I try to predict the similar training images.

I have checked that the keras data generator outputs are fine and they are producing images properly, so i am assuming there is something wrong either in my model/ the way I am trying to predict new images.
I am using a basic UNet with 5 layers at each encoder and decoder-like section, I am also using BN layer and Maxpool layers after Conv layer.I am using drpout layer also.

I am completely confused about the issue as I can not find where the bug is.
Please help !

````
import numpy as np 
import os

import numpy as np
from keras.models import *
from keras.layers import *
from keras.optimizers import *
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, LearningRateScheduler
from keras import backend as keras


def gunet1(input_size = (992,992,3)):
    inputs = Input(input_size)
    conv1 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same')(inputs)
    conv1 = BatchNormalization()(conv1)
    #conv1 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same')(conv1)
    pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv1)
    conv2 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same')(pool1)
    conv2 = BatchNormalization()(conv2)
    #conv2 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same')(conv2)
    pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv2)
    conv3 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same')(pool2)
    conv3 = BatchNormalization()(conv3)
    #conv3 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same')(conv3)
    pool3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv3)
    conv4 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same')(pool3)
    conv4 = BatchNormalization()(conv4)
    #conv4 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same')(conv4)
    drop4 = Dropout(0.2)(conv4)
    pool4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(drop4)
    
    conv5 = Conv2D(1024, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same')(pool4)
    conv5 = BatchNormalization()(conv5)
    #conv5 = Conv2D(1024, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same')(conv5)
    drop5 = Dropout(0.2)(conv5)

    up6 = Conv2D(512, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same')(UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(drop5))
    merge6 = concatenate([drop4,up6], axis = 3)
    #conv6 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same')(merge6)
    conv6 = BatchNormalization()(merge6)
    #conv6 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same')(conv6)

    up7 = Conv2D(256, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same')(UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(conv6))
    merge7 = concatenate([conv3,up7], axis = 3)
    #conv7 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same')(merge7)
    conv7 = BatchNormalization()(merge7)
    #conv7 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same')(conv7)

    up8 = Conv2D(128, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same')(UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(merge7))
    merge8 = concatenate([conv2,up8], axis = 3)
    #conv8 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same')(merge8)
    conv8 = BatchNormalization()(up8)
    #conv8 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same')(conv8)

    up9 = Conv2D(64, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same')(UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(merge8))
    merge9 = concatenate([conv1,up9], axis = 3)
    #conv9 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same')(merge9)
    conv9 = BatchNormalization()(merge9)
    #conv9 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same')(conv9)
    #conv9 = Conv2D(2, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same')(conv9)
    conv10 = Conv2D(3, 1, activation = 'sigmoid')(conv9)
    #conv10 = BatchNormalization()(conv10)

    model = Model(input = inputs, output = conv10)
    
    model=multi_gpu_model(model,gpus=9)
    model.compile(optimizer = Adam(lr = 1e-4),  loss='mean_squared_error', metrics = ['mean_squared_error'])

    return model    

model = gunet1()

model.fit_generator(generator=my_generator, steps_per_epoch= 100,validation_steps=100, validation_data=my_val_generator,  epochs= 10,callbacks=callbacks)

prediction =model.predict_generator(val_image_data_generator, 4)

plt.imshow(prediction[0])  ##This gives complete black image
```
````

Comment: Could you possibly share code snippets of the referred bits you asked in the question?

Comment: Edited. Thanks !